# TypeError: violinplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quantiles'

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, violin-plot

I'm trying to make a violin plot that shows the 0.25 and 0.75 quantiles, but keep getting a TypeError, despite the documentation suggesting this is a valid keyword.

Here is my code:

```
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 1, wspace=0.15, hspace=0.1)

plotplag = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0])

plotplag.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
plotplag.violinplot([S95BCore_an, S95BRim_an, S98Core_an, S98Rim_an, VHCoreLZ_an, VHRimLZ_an, VHCoreUZ_an, VHRimUZ_an], showmeans=True, quantiles=[[0.75], [0.25]])
plotplag.set_xticklabels(['S95B Core', 'S95B Rim', 'S98 Core', 'S98 Rim', 'MS LZ Core', 'MS LZ Rim', 'MS UZ Core', 'MS UZ Rim'])

plotplag.set_ylabel('An# (mol. %)', fontsize=16)
```

Comment: I'm running 3.1.3

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html doesn't mention the `quantiles` parameter. It seems to be added in 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `quantiles = [0.75, 0.25]` instead of `quantiles=[[0.75], [0.25]]` ?  Going off of examples here: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/statistics/violinplot.html

It could also be a version issue: from the command line try:

```
$ pip install -U matplotlib
```

Comment: Hmm...is your matplotlib up to date?  If it's not recognizing 'quantiles' as a parameter it could be a version issue.

Comment: Turns out it was a version issue! Updated and now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your quantilse should be a list, i.e.

```
quantiles =[0.75, 0.25])
```